# How to determine if the generator returned from `yield scrapy.Request` has any data?

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

In the [Scrapy Tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests), the spider extracts the next page links from `class="next"` and crawls them -

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

For my case, I can't find the next page links in the files downloaded from the webserver but I know the format is `response.url` concatenated with `/page/[page number]/`. Requested pages which don't yield quotes still return a `response`, for example - [No quotes found!](http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/11/). Since the number of next pages is normally less than 20, I could loop over all the possible urls by replacing last 3 lines of the spider with -

```
for page_num in range(2, 20):
    yield response.follow(f"/page/{page_num}/", callback=self.parse)
```

However this forces the spider to request pages (such as http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/11 to 20) which don't yield quotes. How can I adjust my spider to terminate the `page_num` loop after requesting the first page which does not yield quotes? (such as http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/11)

pseudo code -

```
    page_num = 2
    while (quotes are yielded from the response):
        yield response.follow(f"/page/{page_num}/", callback=self.parse)
        page_num += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use result of `response.css('..')` as condition to next page.
In this case Your code will be like this:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        page_num = get_pagenumber_from_url(response.url)
        
        quotes_sel = response.css('div.quote'):
        # quotes_sel - will be SelectorList if page have item data
        # quotes_sel - will be None if page doesn't have item data
        for quote in quotes_sel:
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        if quotes_sel:
            next_page_url = f"/page/{str(page_num+1)}"
            yield response.follow(next_page_url , callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks @Georgiy Great answer! but one small correction in your comment - `# quotes_sel - will be [] if page doesn't have item data`